# Change Pages with Transition

Tags: javascript, transition

I'm using divs to make an OnePage Site but I found some problems when the "refresh page" is needed. I can't use the ID a href in this case, but I need to use transitions to change the pages.

Can I redirect from `index.html` to `page2.html` using a slide effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Look into [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) you can slide between pages with.

Here is sample JS from the plugin:

```
$(function(){
    $("#site").cycle({
        fx : "scrollHorz",
        next : ".next a",
        prev : ".prev a",
        startingSlide : 1,
        timeout : 0
    });
  });​
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/zLekb/) for a demo of the effect.

Another option you can use does not require a plugin, below is a great tutorial on that method.

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

Comment: Thank you, Gothburz! This Fiddle use the ID's anchor, which I can't choose for my site, but the Cycle plugin is very interesting. I just don't know how use it to insert a transition between the main page and other external link.

Comment: No Problem! You can also check out this tutorial on how to use transition effects between pages. http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/